# How to switch between 2 User Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been trying to figure out these past 2 days how to  switch between 2 User Controls back and forward with buttons inside those User Controls.
I managed to make this happen but with the buttons outside those User Controls.

[This is how my project files look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WtEI.png)

BaseCommand.cs

```
public class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _method;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
    {
        _method = method;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _method.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ICommand LogInCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand SetupCommand { get; set; }

    private object selectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel

    {

        get { return selectedViewModel; }

        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }

    }



    public MainViewModel()

    {

        LogInCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenLogIn);

        SetupCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenSetup);

    }

    private void OpenLogIn(object obj)

    {

        SelectedViewModel = new LogInViewModel();

    }

    private void OpenSetup(object obj)

    {

        SelectedViewModel = new SetupViewModel();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)

    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)

        {

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }

    }

}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>

    <Button Content="Open LogIn" Height="24" Command="{Binding LogInCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Open Setup" Height="24" Command="{Binding SetupCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

LoginViewModel and SetupViewModel are empty classes and their corresponding views have a text block indicating what they are.
What I want is to have instead 2 buttons in my MainWindow.xaml I want 1 in my LogInView.xaml that opens SetupView.xaml and vice versa.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:LogInViewModel}">
        <views:LogInView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SetupViewModel}">
        <views:SetupView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move "Open Setup" button to `LogInView` and "Open LogIn" button to `SetupView`.

In `LogInViewModel` create `SetupCommand` and pass the `MainViewModel` in the ctor. When the button "Open Setup" is clicked and `SetupCommand` is invoked then call new `OpenSetup` method on the `MainViewModel`.

```
public class LogInViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged // etc.
{
    private readonly MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    public ICommand SetupCommand { get; set; }

    public LogInViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        SetupCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenSetup);
    }

    private void OpenSetup(object obj)
    {
        mainViewModel.OpenSetup();
    }
    ....
}
```

Similar for `SetupViewModel`

```
public class SetupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged // etc.
{
    private readonly MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    public ICommand LogInCommand { get; set; }

    public SetupViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        LogInCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenLogIn);
    }

    private void OpenLogIn(object obj)
    {
        mainViewModel.OpenLogIn();
    }
    ....
}
```

Finally, remove commands from `MainViewModel`, modify `OpenLogIn` and `OpenSetup` methods and pass reference to the `MainViewModel` when you create new instance of `LogInViewModel` or `SetupViewModel`.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object selectedViewModel;
    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        OpenLogIn();
    }

    public void OpenLogIn()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new LogInViewModel(this);
    }

    public void OpenSetup()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new SetupViewModel(this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```